# @ConditionalOnProperty not reflected when viewing @Autowired beans in Intellij IDEA

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

Let's say I have `@Configuration` class which registers bean of type `RestClient` conditionally using `@ConditionalOnProperty`.

```
@Configuration
public class RestClientConfig {

    @Bean("restClient")
    @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "rest.client", name = "enabled", havingValue = "false", matchIfMissing = true)
    public RestClient restClient(RestProperties properties) {
        return new HttpRestClient(...);
    }

    @Bean("restClient")
    @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "rest.client", name = "enabled", havingValue = "true")
    public RestClient mockRestClient(RestProperties properties) {
        return new MockRestClient();
    }

}
```

When I run this application, everything works. Implementation of given type is chosen correctly when I autowire `RestClient` in another bean.

However, when I view this setup in Intellij IDEA, it reports:
[image]

Is there a way to instruct Intellij to know about `@ConditionalOnProperty` or do it in different way in Spring Boot?

Comment: Could you please post a minimal sample project in our issue tracker? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA Thanks.

Comment: @YannCébron is there any fix for that bug?